# get the tag name and id of a child node

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an html that looks like this

```
<div id="tabs"> 

  <ul id="ul_id"> 
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab 1</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab 2</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">tab 3</a></li> 
  </ul> 

  <div id="tabs-1"> <p>tab 1 contents</p> </div> 
  <div id="tabs-2"> <p>tab 2 contents</p> </div> 
  <div id="tabs-3"> <p>tab 3 contents</p> </div>

</div>
```

What I need to do is make this code dynamic because the number of tabs is not fixed.

What I have done so far is this

```
<script>
  par = document.createElement('p')
  par.setAttribute("text","Adding nodes");
  dib = document.createElement('div')
  dib.setAttribute("id","tabs-4");
  dib.appendChild(par);
  test=document.getElementById("tabs")
  test.appendChild(dib);
  for(i=0; i< test.childNodes.length; i++)
  {
    document.getElementsByName
    if(test.childNodes[i].getAttribute("id") == "ul_id")
      alert("equal");
    else
      alert(test.childNodes[i].getAttribute("id"));
  }
</script>
```

Create an element for `<p>`

Create an element for `div`

Append(appendChild) the div element to tabs

Now Im stuck with the part of getting the tag name and id name of the child nodes of tag..
I need to add the new entry to the list.

How will I do that?

i thought of using `getElementsByName` but that would mean that I need to add a name attribute to the `ul`. Im not sure if that was a good idea so I Im thinking of other possible ways to do it. Please help. thanks

Comment: have you considered the use of a js library like [jquery](http://www.jquery.com) ? it exposes a full-fledged css selector syntax to reference dom elements. with this tool you can non-intrusively add as much information to your html elements as you like by defining `data-` attributes and operate on your html by selecting elements where certain `data-` attributes have specific values. (the library is extremely useful in many other regards, too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a tab looks like it should be something done as a function rather than inline, so you could write it like this

```
                                 // i is the last id
var addTab = (function (tab_root, nav_root, i) { // IIFE to create closure
    return function (title, contents) {
        var li, a, div, j;
        // get id
        j = ++i; // I put it in it's own var to avoid race conditions
        // create nav
        li = document.createElement('li');
        a = document.createElement('a');
        a.setAttribute('href', '#tabs-' + j);
        if (title) a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
        li.appendChild(a);
        // create tab
        div =  document.createElement('div');
        if (contents) div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(contents));
        // append to document
        tab_root.appendChild(div);
        nav_root.appendChild(li);
        return {tab: div, nav: a, id: j};
    }
}(document.getElementById('tabs'), document.getElementById('ul_id'), 3)());
// invoke IIFE with initials i.e. id 3 for 3 tabs existing
```

now

```
addTab('tab 4', 'tab 4 contents');
```

An *Object* is returned with properties *tab*, *nav* and *id*. This lets you do more work with the different parts as required.